# OpenGL rotating a 2D texture

Tags: c++, c, opengl, rotation, 2d

UPDATE

See bottom for update.

---

I've been looking alot around the internet and I have found a few tutorials that explain what I'm trying to achieve but I can't get it to work, either the tutorial is incomplete or not applicable on my code.

I'm trying something as simple as rotating a 2D image around its origin (center).

I use xStart, xEnd, yStart and yEnd to flip the texture which are either 0 or 1.

This is what the code looks like

```
GameRectangle dest = destination;
Vector2 position = dest.getPosition();

glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);

glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, this->image);

//If the rotation isn't 0 we'll rotate it
if (rotation != 0)
{
    glMatrixMode(GL_TEXTURE);

    glLoadIdentity();
    glTranslatef(0.5, 0.5, 0);
    glRotatef(rotation, 0, 0, 1);

    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
}

glBegin(GL_QUADS);
glTexCoord2d(xStart,yStart);
glVertex2f(position.x, position.y);

glTexCoord2d(xEnd,yStart);
glVertex2f(position.x + this->bounds.getWidth(), position.y);

glTexCoord2d(xEnd,yEnd); 
glVertex2f(position.x + this->bounds.getWidth(), position.y + this->bounds.getHeight());

glTexCoord2d(xStart,yEnd);
glVertex2f(position.x, position.y + this->bounds.getHeight());

glEnd();

glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);

//Reset the rotation so next object won't be rotated
glMatrixMode(GL_TEXTURE);

glLoadIdentity();
glRotatef(0, 0, 0, 1);

glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
```

This code will draw the image in it's original size and it will rotate it, but it will rotate it from the top left corner which crops the image a lot. By calling GameRectangle.getOrigin() I can easily get the center of the rectangle, but I don't know where to use it.

Bit if put:

```
 glTranslatef(-0.5, -0.5, 0);
```

After I call the:

```
 glRotatef(0.5, 0.5, 0);
```

It will rotate from the center, but it will strech the image if it's not a perfect 90 degrees rotation.

UPDATE

---

After trying pretty much everything possible, I got the result I was looking for.

But I'm not sure if this is the best approach. Please tell me if there's something wrong with my code.

As I mentioned in a comment above, I use the same image multiple times and draw it with different values, so I can't save anything to the actual image. So I must reset the values everytime after I have rendered it.

I changed my code to this:

```
//Store the position temporary
GameRectangle dest = destination;
Vector2 position = dest.getPosition();

glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);

glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, this->image);

glTranslatef(dest.getOrigin().x, dest.getOrigin().y, 0);
glRotatef(rotation, 0, 0, 1);

glBegin(GL_QUADS);
glTexCoord2d(xStart,yStart);
glVertex2f(-dest.getWidth()/2, -dest.getHeight()/2);

glTexCoord2d(xEnd,yStart);
glVertex2f(dest.getWidth()/2, -dest.getHeight()/2);

glTexCoord2d(xEnd,yEnd); 
glVertex2f(dest.getWidth()/2, dest.getHeight()/2);

glTexCoord2d(xStart,yEnd);
glVertex2f(-dest.getWidth()/2, dest.getHeight()/2);

glEnd();

//Reset the rotation and translation
glRotatef(-rotation,0,0,1);
glTranslatef(-dest.getOrigin().x, -dest.getOrigin().y, 0);

glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
```

This rotates the texture together with the quad it's drawn in, it doesn't strech or crop. However the edges are a bit jagged if the image is filled square but I guess I can't avoid that with out antialiasing.

Comment: Do you really want to rotate the texture and not the quad? In any case, if you are already using the OpenGL matrices, you should use the matrix stack, i.e., glPushMatrix and glPopMatrix, instead of resetting the matrix at the end of your code.

Comment: If just rotating the quad is enough I guess that's what want.
Will that rotate the texture with the quad and how do rotate the quad properly?

Comment: Also, I'm not sure where to call glPushMatrix() and glPopMatrix(), where ever I put them I don't get the desired result, it either rotates all images or no images.

I don't know if it makes any difference, but I draw the same image multiple times but with different values for rotation etc, so I can't save anything to the actual image.

Comment: In general, before you change any matrix, you do something like this:
glMatrixMode(...); glPushMatrix(); doStuff(); glPopMatrix();

Have you tried enabling filtering via glTexEnv and see if it helps with your jagged edges?

Comment: My "engine" looks a lot like the XNA framework where I call renderer.begin() which does:
  glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
  glPushMatrix();

  glOrtho(0, frameWidth, frameHeight, 0, -1, 1);

and then renderer.end()

that does: 

  glPopMatrix();
  SDL_GL_SwapBuffers();

And in between I draw every individual object.

So I use glPopMatrix and PushMatrix(), but not quite as you suggested.

Sorry but I don't know anything about glTexEnv, but I did try glEnable(GL_POLYGON_SMOOTH) which fixed the jagged edges but then draws a white/transparent diagonal line through my quads. :S

Comment: Actually I meant [glTexParameter](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glTexParameter.xml), so you can enable Mip-Mapping or at least linear filtering. If you do a glPushMatrix in your updated code right before the glTranslatef and a glPopMatrix after glEnd, you do not need to "undo" your rotation, thus saving several unnecessary floating point operations. It might not be a problem now, but it can turn into one pretty fast :D

Comment: I managed to get the push and pop to work correctly, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is this:

```
glPushMatrix(); //Save the current matrix.
//Change the current matrix.
glTranslatef(dest.getOrigin().x, dest.getOrigin().y, 0);
glRotatef(rotation, 0, 0, 1);

glBegin(GL_QUADS);
glTexCoord2d(xStart,yStart);
glVertex2f(-dest.getWidth()/2, -dest.getHeight()/2);

glTexCoord2d(xEnd,yStart);
glVertex2f(dest.getWidth()/2, -dest.getHeight()/2);

glTexCoord2d(xEnd,yEnd); 
glVertex2f(dest.getWidth()/2, dest.getHeight()/2);

glTexCoord2d(xStart,yEnd);
glVertex2f(-dest.getWidth()/2, dest.getHeight()/2);

glEnd();

//Reset the current matrix to the one that was saved.
glPopMatrix();
```

Comment: Do you by any chance happen to know how this would be done in OpenGL ES 2.0?