# openGL 2D pixel rotation

Tags: c, opengl

I'm trying to rotate a 2D pixel matrix, but nothing actually happens.
my origin is a stored `bitmap[w x h x 3]`.
why isn't the shown image being rotated?
Here's the display function:

```
void display() 
{
    uint32_t    i = 0,j = 0,k = 0;
    unsigned char   pixels[WINDOW_WIDTH * WINDOW_HEIGHT * 3];

    memset(pixels, 0, sizeof(pixels));
    for(j = bitmap_h -1; j > 0; j--) {
        for(i = 0; i < bitmap_w; i++) {
            pixels[k++]=bitmap[j][i].r;
            pixels[k++]=bitmap[j][i].g;
            pixels[k++]=bitmap[j][i].b;
        }
    }
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT); 

    glRotatef(90,0,0,1);    
    glDrawPixels(g_img.descriptor.size_w, g_img.descriptor.size_h, GL_RGB,  GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, &pixels);

    glutSwapBuffers();
}
```

Comment: *"nothing actually happens"*. The program doesn't run? Or, no image is displayed? Or, an unrotated image is displayed?

Comment: If you look up `glRotatef`, it says — *"multiply the current matrix by a rotation matrix"*. Do you have a current matrix?

Comment: `memset(pixels, 0, sizeof(pixels))` zeros-out the size of the type of `pixels` - which should be a pointer. You very likely want `*pixels`.

Comment: @Olaf I edited the question so you can more easily see `pixels` defined. But image memory would be better from `malloc()` than on the stack so you would *expect* to see `*pixels`.

Comment: @WeatherVane: Sorry, I really just looked at the formatted code.

Comment: @user1262882 is this previous question any help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9312486/opengl-rotating-a-2d-texture

Answer (score 4):

First and foremost glDrawPixels should not be used. The problem you have is one of the reasons. The convoluted rules by which glDrawPixels operate are too vast to outline here, let's just say, that there's a so called "raster position" in your window, at which glDrawPixels will place the lower left corner of the image it draws. No transformation whatsoever will be applied to the image.

However when setting the raster position, that's when transformations get applied. And should, for whatever reason, the raster position lie outside the visible window nothing will get drawn at all.

Solution: Don't use glDrawPixels. *Don't use glDrawPixels.* *DON'T USE glDrawPixels.* I repeat ***DON'T USE glDrawPixels.*** It's best you completely forget that this function actually exists in legacy OpenGL.

Use a textured quad instead. That will also transform properly.

Answer (score 0):

I did something similar.  I'm creating a 3D space shooter game using OpenGL/C++.  For one of my levels, I have a bunch of asteroids/rocks in the background each rotating and moving at a random speed.

I did this by taking the asteroid bitmap image and creating a texture.  Then I applied the texture to a square (`glBegin(GL_QUADS)`). Each time I draw the square, I multiply each of the vertex coordinates (`glVertex3f(x, y, z)`) with a rotation matrix.

```
|cos0  -sin0|

|sin0  cos0 |
```

`0` is the theta angle.  I store this angle as part of my `Asteroid` class.  each iteration I increment it by a value, depending on how fast I want the asteroid to spin.  It works great.